# how to deal with OP asking another questions after answering original question

Tags: discussion

I have faced this problem multiple times and dont know how to deal with it.

I did answer a question which was initially asked by OP. Then OP added another question that also was answered. again OP asked third question. All questions by editing the original question.

How to deal with such people. Problem is not with answering, but the fact that OP is not trying things after first answer. He/she just thinks that we should solve all the issues they face. Rather than they thinking and trying things, they just keep asking.

Should I ask OP to have a new question for every question asked after answering it. But it would be painful for OP to keep writing same information all over again.

One option I see is closing the question : but then I would loose my points, as my answer was accepted. Is there any other way to deal with such OP/questions??

Comment: @gnat That does not look like a duplicate to me. It uses this case as an example, but the topic of the question is actually quite different. What you suggested as a duplicate is about introducing a mechanism for quickly providing canned comments.

Comment: @RetoKoradi http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common Stack Exchange term for what you're describing is "chameleon question". There is a question with an extensive set of answers about the topic on Meta Stack Exchange:

[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)