# How to guide a beginner that needs more help than just the answer

Tags: discussion, new-users

Warning: this is NOT a duplicate of [How handle questions that are beyond OP's knowledge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285005/how-handle-questions-that-are-beyond-ops-knowledge) .

What I want to know here is the correct protocol to **further** help someone after answering her/his question. What should I do if I feel that a user that posted a question needs more help than my complete and clear answer. I am worried the user won't be able to get trough all of what I have just said.
You know that kind of user you recognize because he posted a very broad question, where he didn't even provide code that he tried. You recognize it because you were in the exact same spot a couple years ago, you didn't know what APIs were, frameworks ?, work environments ? IDE ?

Should I invite that user in a chat ? private ? in the comments ?
What should I do if the user has less than 10 rep, invite him in a not stack-overflow chat ?

I don't ask if I should care about that internet person, but what to do if I care. Because I see my old self in that user.

Is it better to invite him via email ? What would you do ?

edit: the question is answered by me but I feel they are going to be stuck in the next step easily, edit 2: it is not a duplicate

Comment: On a Q& A site for professional and enthusiast programmers?  Nothing.

Comment: Do whatever you want with your time. If you want to help that person, do so in whichever way you please.

Comment: Sure, take him to chat.  Beware that there are a hundred thousand more, the 3rd isn't going to be so exciting.  We try to help all of them at the same time, best done through somebody who knows how to ask the question.

Comment: My question is not how to handle question correctly but, how to help *after* the question, how should I contact the person so that I can give him more tips and ask on what he is working on and perhaps give him tips about code the user wrote

Answer (score 1):

I worked as a teacher's aid at my school for a few semesters in introductory programming and data structures. The way I see it, on ambiguous beginner stack overflow questions, there are two approaches you can take to help them.

- leave comments to get them to refine their questions.

Say that no one can help them until they post concise code and stack traces that result from it. What is the error, where does it occur, and what does this imply? The basis of engineering and problem solving is breaking the problem into small manageable parts to solve a larger overarching problem. It is a skill which they kind of have to learn.

- Assume they are performing a common operation and provide a common answer.

One of the things about beginner questions is, they're probably doing some very common operations: opening files, manipulating data structures, things like that. Assume that this is their aim and provide a generic example.

This gives them a basis to work from. They can comment on your answer looking for the more refined details from there, and you can update it to meet their specific needs.

Comment: Teaching is different, you can guide them to work on the right kind of projects.  SO users often want to do things like hacking their favorite game or controlling the fan in their computer.  The kind they can't succeed at.

Comment: yeah, answers a bit contextual. It's more like if someone is asking "open file with python and see if each line has question mark??" or something. Beginner level type questions