# What is the protocol about answering homework assignments?

Tags: discussion, homework

I recently saw a question about a homework assignment and the OP had tried his best to show the code he had below the assignment text. But he clearly did not understand the assignment and he got derailed by it, making things up in his code that were never even asked for.

It got downvoted for reasons I still can't understand as it was clear that it was a homework assignment and this student was clearly struggling with programming. He was also new so I consider that a bit rude as it got downvoted without comments, plus two "close" votes as the question seemed unclear. (Basically, it is: do my homework!)

So I wrote an answer and as a very experienced software developer, I used a solution that is far more advanced that a beginner would understand, yet it followed the assignment to the letter. I also pointed out that he would never convince his teacher that he wrote it, unless he could explain all the details in it. Still, the answer should compile and show him what his code is supposed to do. He can now focus on writing his own solution, try to understand the things I did and provide his teacher with my code while explaining how he got it and ask the teacher if he could explain how my solution works. So it's useful, educational and he can't cheat with my answer.

But what is the protocol for answering homework assignments? I saw a hopelessly lost student so I provided a working solution and hope to trigger him to explore and learn from it, as his teacher will not believe that he wrote it.

*Is this the right way to answer homework assignments?*

Comment: Your question seems to be more "what to do with people who are hopelessly lost", the fact that it is about homework is just a really specific example you encountered in the wild. Hopelessly lost people need tutoring, this is not a tutoring site. All you can do is deal with the content according to its quality.

Comment: @Gimby, I am more curious if providing a real but complex answer is the right thing to do in these cases. The OP is unlikely to understand why the answer works, but he will see that it works.

Comment: I don't find that type of answer valuable. What's the point of blasting somebody in the face with information they won't understand? It usually looks like a weird flex rather than an honest attempt to be helpful. I say either take the time to answer them at their level, slowly and pedagogically, or just move on to a better question.

Comment: Regarding "OPs knowledge level": [How handle questions that are beyond OP's knowledge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285005/how-handle-questions-that-are-beyond-ops-knowledge)

Comment: Your answer didn't help one bit. First, question is too broad and unclear. We have no idea what is the actual problem(s). Anything short of step by step explanation of how and why for each part of the homework is basically useless. If you really wanted to help you should have asked for some clarifications about what are the issues OP is facing. Whether it is algorithm itself, using language... but even then it is hard to say how much you could have helped.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Did you even read the question? OPposted the assignment followed by the code he'd written so far and the note that he didn't understand it anymore. Made sense, as the code he wrote didn't get even close to any solution. But what he was supposed to do was quite clear. Why he couldn't understand it? In my opinion because he didn't know what the output should be. My answer provides him the output and some additional learning material if he wants to understand my solution. Otherwise, He could use my solution and discuss it with his teacher, thus get more training.

Comment: Yes, I read the question. You still don't know what is the actual problem.

Comment: Question says: "I have a homework assignment and I don't understand it that well. Can you solve it for me?"

Comment: (Sorry, but I have to say it) Good boy! You did what he asked... Again, main problem here is that you don't know which part of the homework OP does not understand. You can only wild guess from his code mess. And all you did was wall of code and no explanation. It is hard to expect that any student on same   skill level as OP will be capable of analyzing that code and learning from it in meaningful way. If you had walk through explaining the algorithm and every line of code then your answer would teach something and it could be helpful to others besides OP (now it is hardly useful to OP, too)