# When is it ok to extend a question with another question, after initial answers have been posted?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627409/how-to-install-mosh-on-an-emr-master) recently, which had a bounty placed.  After the bounty was placed, an answer was generated.  In response to the bounty, the poster then mentioned in comments that they were now encountering another issue, and were updating their question to include this new issue.  I politely asked the poster to consider a new question for the new issue, to which their response was:

> the bounty is on the question precisely as it was when it was placed, however the answer as it is does not solve fully the issue ...

The way I read this, the poster is essentially acknowledging that there is no way that the person providing the answer could have answered the question fully, as they didn't have the additional information required when they provided the answer.  To me, that makes the secondary error a completely new question, and shouldn't be considered in the completeness of an answer.  Having a bounty awarded to one answer and another answer later marked as the accepted answer is confusing, to say the least.

Am I correct in my line of thinking on this?

Comment: Just from your title (without inspecting your particular sample): _"When is it ok to addend a question with another question?"_ Never. That's what comments are for usually. There are cases though, where XY problems might be pointed out in answers, and left with a question mark asking what the OP actually wants to achieve.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in this case, the poster was asking how to install a service, and once the answer for the installation was provided, they then were not able to communicate with said service, but suggest that because they can't communicate with it, the install wasn't fully resolved.

Comment: `...my new issue` says it all - new issue should mean New Question. The new issue could have a different answer from a different user.  Then there is wailing and gnashing of teeth by the one who feels cheated.

Comment: I agree that this looks like two separate questions. I'm not familiar with the topics at hand but this, _"This has solved the installation issue"_ says to me that the answer given solved the original question. It seems to me that if they keep adding on to the question, it will end up that question is too broad. It isn't fair for a user to get around the "too broad" description by asking it piece-meal like this.

Comment: A [chameleon question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275138/2564301) but with a bounty. That's new. I guess the [recommended exit strategies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) will not work and the bounty-supplier will just hold on to it until it expires (then the Best So Far gets half the spoils).

Comment: @Jongware but the poster already awarded the bounty to the answer provided, while simultaneously asking for new answers.

Comment: I don't think that is really a dupe of this question.

Comment: @Claies: "addend" *is* an English word, but it doesn't mean what you're using it to mean. In this case, just "add" is the verb you want: "When is it ok to **add** a question **to** another question?"

Comment: I think you're after "append".

Comment: Specifically, *addend* is concerning adding numbers; *append* is adding texts

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ _"That's what comments are for usually"_ No, it _absolutely_ is not!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is never okay to append a new issue to an existing question. An appropriate response is to edit out that second issue and ask the OP to post it in a new question.

In some cases, if you see that the incoming answers are missing the point a little bit, it is arguably okay to append a *rephrased version* of the question to improve clarity ("in other words, ...") as long as it's the same underlying thing you're asking about; not a new issue.

In the case you highlight, however, the OP unambiguously states in his [comment to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627409/how-to-install-mosh-on-an-emr-master/30720578#comment49534152_30720578) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VTKN.png)) that this answer solves the problem:

> Thanks, This has **solved** the installation issue, [...]

and that now he wants more help on something different:

> [...] I've updated the question with my **new issue**.

(emphasis mine)

Verdict: Not okay.

Action: I just edited out that second question and suggested the OP post it as a new, separate question.

Comment: Clarifying good, changing bad.

Comment: I'm the OP, I think I misphrased  my update, I disagree that I added an entirely new question, just the next issue encountered in attempting to resolve the question. I've gone into more detail in my own answer.

Comment: @theheadofabroom You asked how to install mosh.  It is installed.  Your next problem is how to connect to mosh remotely.  The full question -- your motivation  -- "how do I solve my ssh termination problems" is too broad to be a stack overflow question, and it isn't what you asked either.  Now, including the motivation is good (sometimes, this lets answers bypass your narrow issue); but adding a second question along the path to reach your motivation isn't good.  Good SO questions should be narrow technical ones that are well framed.

Comment: It's not installed if it's not configured, configuration isn't some optional step. Without configuring it, having the binary is useless

Comment: @theheadofabroom You have localhost working.  So it is installed.  You suspect the problem involves NAT, which means your problem is connecting to it over a NAT.  Getting network services through a NAT is an orthogonal problem to your original one, about installing some software, and adding "can you debug my NAT issues" to your question is changing the scope of the question.  As I said, your question (how do I install this) doesn't solve *every* problem you have, but solving *every* problem you have is too broad for a single SO question.  Break your problems down to smaller bits.

Comment: @theheadofabroom - It's hard to hit a moving target. If you got a quote on fixing the engine of your car because it wouldn't start and the mechanic fixed it would you then expect them to fix the non-working transmission because 'it is all the same problem' and you need both to get going?

Comment: @theheadofabroom: Your initial question was answered. Once that happens, it is inappropriate to then change the question to include an entirely different problem. It invalidates existing answers or makes them look incomplete, and in either case can negatively impact the reputation of those people who were kind enough to provide those answers. If you now have a *secondary* issue, ask a new question and ask there. If you need to link back to the first one for reference, feel free to do so.

Comment: There appears to be an impasse here as to what is one question or two, what was included from the phrasing or just background flavour. From my point of view what matters is that future visitors see a good complete answer that solves a problem fully. In this case setting up a Mosh server on EMR such that it can be used. Surely this is what the site is for? As for reputation, I have the answerer a good bit of my own reputation, I don't see the issue.

Comment: I explained the issue  here and to your  post. It's the chameleon question problem, where the question evolves after receiving answers to the original question. Any changes invalidate the answers you've already received, and often negatively impact those users kind enough to answer your question. When you change the requirements for the question, theiranswers become incomplete, invalid or wrong because you've moved the target. If you offer a bounty on a question that has certain content, and you get an answer based on that content, **don't change the question*. Ask a new one instead.

Answer (score -5):

OP here.

On this instance the question was about getting Mosh working on EMR. I highlighted what I'd done so far and the issue I'd run into. The answer solved the first issue I'd run into, but the setup was not complete.

The bounty was to get attention for the question, and I felt that the answerer had fulfilled that requirement. I still had an issue doing what the question stated I wanted to do, so I added an update making this explicit. The answerer them updated his answer and while I have not yet had a chance to test this. I anticipate this being the end of my problem, at which point I will accept the answer.

I don't see that the update was a second question, and I don't feel that the original question was resolved - what would be the dividing line for this?

From my point of view, someone wanting to achieve this and arriving from Google, would not resolve their issue without the second part, and so it seems necessary for a complete answer. It's this not the point we're supposed to be aiming for?

Comment: You are free to link between questions. For instance, ask a new question, then update the old one with a link to the new one, and link from the new to the old. That would be in keeping with Stack Overflow's requirement that questions don't get broader, and allow people to find the answers they are looking for.