# What to do when a user edits their post to add a second unrelated question?

Tags: discussion

What is the correct course of action when a user edits their post to add another question? They have already received an answer for the "first" question and then edited it, copying in another question they have asked in another post. Apparently they have done this because the other question wasn't getting any answers and thought they would have more luck a pending it to a question that had an answer.

Mutant double question
[Skipping a key parameter in couchbase map function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35764921/39392)

Separate second question
[couchbase view using multiple keys to get result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35890289/39392)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it ok to extend a question with another question, after initial answers have been posted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275138/how-to-deal-with-op-asking-another-questions-after-answering-original-question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Roll the edit back.  If the author re-applies it, flag for moderator attention so that they can roll it back and then lock the post.

Comment: Although technically optional, I would still suggest leaving a comment explaining *why* you rolled back their edit. That way, there will be no doubt that their re-application of the edit was a flagrant violation of the community expectations, rather than a simple misunderstanding. (Probably not at issue in this particular case, but users who append follow-on questions might genuinely not understand why this is bad.)

Answer (score 4):

Rollback and add the following as a comment:

> Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.