# Can a moderator lock this revision edit war?

Tags: support, specific-question

> I got moderator flag banned for a comment on an unrelated
>   question/answer comment that was flagged rude/offensive deleted by the
>   moderator and then marked "declined" so I can not post this to the
>   regular flag system right now.

Please someone lock [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk) or delete it as it is a duplicate and off topic. But the revision that I reverted to is the revision that was answered and accepted. Someone else completely vandalized the question with a completely different question which generated a crap load of derision in the comments and other *"answers"* that are completely irrelevant to the original question.

Now people are reverting the question back to the vandalized version because they do not know how to read for comprehension.

Regardless of how poor the original question was/is, the vandalized edit changed the entire context and meaning from the original.

Here is the vandalism edit by someone that was **not** the owner in question for those that might now can view the edit history.

[image]

What is more concerning is why this edit was accepted since the code that was added never existed before the above edit and the changes to the requirements completely change the intent and context of the original question.

Comment: I'm surprised that an edit by someone other than the Asker that completely replaces the Asker's content with a new question got approved in the first place.

Comment: I don't get it, it was the question owner that made the big change 2 years ago in an attempt to get the question re-opened.  That worked.  Why would you now want to restore it to the crappy version that got closed?  The editor certainly made a good-faith attempt to restore the damage you did.

Comment: @HansPassant the question owner is `AlikElzin-kilaka` not `Stephan`. Is the edit history confusing on who **asked** vs who **edited**? `Stephan` added the code it was never in any of the previous edits and they changed the working and left out the requirement of the `List` interface, why they did what they did is just speculation.

Comment: @HansPassant don't know if you noticed but the edit 1) was done two years after question was asked and closed 2) radically changed what was asked ("I don't want `CopyOnWriteArrayList`") and 3) did that change in a way that defaces existing, old, accepted answer ("...CopyOnWriteArrayList in particular"). I am generally a huge fan of [aggressive edits](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2153/168) but I prefer us to draw a line between these and vandalism

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I would say that even if asker themselves added that statement ("I don't want CopyOnWriteArrayList") that late (long after someone posting an answer that suggests it), it would hardly be okay - [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275140/839601) aren't welcome

Answer (score 9):

Given that only a single user decided to undo your roll-back, and only did it once, I'd be willing to wait and see if they try this again. If they do, that might be the point to lock it, but I don't have evidence that this will be an ongoing problem.

We typically step in to lock a question when there's significant back-and-forth over a short period of time, but this was a single edit by someone who would have to go back through review to do it again. I'm thinking they might not try this again, particularly since you confronted them about their edit.

Regarding your comment:

> A moderator already locked the question because of the people that are complaining that the answers do not answer that vandalized version of the question.

I don't see any evidence that a moderator had ever locked this question at any point. It was merely protected and closed by you and others.

Comment: Fair enough, I did not want it to escalate. I mean to say `closed` not `locked` I added a follow up comment to clarify that. `/confronted/educated/g` ;-)